# CloudFormation Lambda S3 bucket access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

In my CloudFormation template I have a lambda whose code lives on S3:

```
MyLambda:
  Properties:
    Code:
      S3Bucket: bucket-name
      S3Key: filename.zip
  Handler: handler
  MemorySize: !Ref 'LambdaMemorySize'
  Role: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXX:role/my-role
  Runtime: python3.6
  Timeout: !Ref 'LambdaTimeout'
Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
```

If I run this from the AWS console, then it works fine. However, when I run this from the AWS CLI (or boto) then it doesn't work, so I guess there must be something missing from my user's credentials that's stopping this working. However my IAM user has administrator access:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message:

```
Your access has been denied by S3, please make sure your request credentials have permission to GetObject for bucket-name/filename.zip. 
S3 Error Code: AccessDenied. S3 Error Message: Access Denied (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: xxxxx)
```

Comment: Is the S3 bucket owned by you? If not, you need to have "Public Read" in those buckets.

Comment: Check S3 bucket policy.

Comment: @Phoenix don't want to make it public

Comment: Verify your policies and ACL.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was due to being part of the group that was doing IP whitelisting - removing that solved this issue.